# Share Permissions: Why can a group access a share, but not members of that group (Windows Server Environment)?

Tags: windows, permissions, file-permissions, share

This is a Windows Server 2012 environment. Several 2012 DCs with just one 08. I have one primary share for everyone.

Through "Advanced Sharing", the groups have full permission, including Authenticated Users, the computers, and Everyone.

Through "Advanced Security", the group has Read and Modify (can not delete subfolders, change perms, or take ownership). In "Effective Access", that group shows the proper permissions, the 3 denied permissions say "Access Limited by File Permissions". ANY user of that group has ALL permissions limited by "File Permissions", and get a couple errors on their PCs.

If using a non-domain PC, they get the filesystem "Access Denied" message with the credentials dialogue (Domain\User and Password). Admin creds WILL work, not this group (Domain Users).

If the PC is on the domain, they simply receive that "Windows can not access this location" message. I am going to the server, then attempting to click on the share, so I know this is not a path issue.

It seems that the permissions are set up for AD, and for the share. I am not sure what else could be going on that only the Admins could access this. It is strange how the group has access, but group members do not.

Sorry if I am unclear, I am new to this website. If you have any questions, I will answer them. Thank you.

-

I recreated the share a little while ago (Stopped Sharing then Shared). I did this a couple times. It seems now the users have access to the 1st directory, but no the 3rd. \ShareDirectory\Any2ndDir\Any3rdDir. It seems to be an issue assigning permissions, as even when i "Replace all child permissions", i do see that the proper groups have not all shown up under these 3rd directories and later.

Comment: "Whoami /Group" shows 50% mandatory groups with unknown SIDs, about 12 wich seems about right.

Comment: Please post more details about the Deny permissions. What exactly are they and who is denied?

Comment: There are no groups set to Deny.I try to take things a couple steps at a time, in case something like this comes up.

Comment: Then I'm not understanding your statement *In "Effective Access", that group shows the proper permissions, the 3 denied permission...*. Please clarify that.

Comment: Okay so after several hours of looking at this, the users of the group are allowed to access the folder in Effective Access, however they are still getting the "could not connect to" message when clicking on the share. I'm rebooting the DC and a client. I'll report back.

Comment: And by that I ment when I go to Effective Access, the Users group has the permissions I set (allowed everything but delete subfolders, change perms, and take owner), however, members of that group where showing no access in the Effective Access area.

Comment: The restart seems to have changed nothing. It seems it gives me "Access Denied" and asks for credentials a few times, then it will go to the other message about not being able to access it.

Comment: I recreated the share a little while ago (Stopped Sharing then Shared). I did this a couple times. It seems now the users have access to the 1st directory, but no the 3rd. \\ShareDirectory\Any2ndDir\Any3rdDir. It seems to be an issue assigning permissions, as even when i "Replace all child permissions", i do see that the proper groups have not all shown up under these 3rd directories and later.